# What password hash algorithm does each version of CentOS use by default?

Tags: centos, password, hash

I'm looking for a table of CentOS versions and corresponding default password hash algorithms. Google searches didn't reveal any matches that look like they have all the information in one place.

Ubuntu publishes [a table like the one I'm looking for](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features) on their wiki.

Answer (score 6):

EL5 and previous versions used MD5 password hashing. EL6 changed to SHA512 password hashing by default. You could put that in a table, but it would be a very small table...